# Integrating (any) map framework in Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, qt5, openstreetmap

I would like to implement any maps (OSM, Google maps...) in my Qt Widget application (only targeting Windows platforms).

All answers I got so far is really out-dated (answers from 2011-2013) and I am not able to google anything useful. So I wanted to ask which frameworks could you recommend me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using the [osgEarth SDK](http://osgearth.org/) in our Qt applications. It supports OSM and basically every map type that is supported by [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/).

Comment: I knew that there must me something newer. This looks pretty much amazing I will take a look.

Comment: Hello my friend.
Recently I've started working with osgEarth. I want to use osgEarth SDK in Qt application. Can you help me whith a simple Qt example?